# Problem with array

Tags: arrays

I'm having some errors while copmiling the following:

```
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1}=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
$A.s.k_{t}^{\alpha}+(1-\delta).b_{t}^{P}-\delta.b_{t}$ \quad \text{if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} < 1$} \\ 
$s.k_{t}^{\alpha}-b_{t}$ \quad \text{if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} \geq 1$}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

It looks as I want in pdf but I'm getting some `missing $ inserted`.
Thanks for your help

Comment: When I use cases instead of array, I get the error extra alignment tab.
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1}=\begin{cases}{A.s.k_{t}^{\alpha}+(1-\delta).b_{t}^{P}-\delta.b_{t} & \quad if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} < 1$ &
 \\ 
 s.k_{t}^{\alpha}-b_{t} & \quad if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} \geq 1$} \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Have also addressed your `cases` comment in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `array` environment is already in math mode, so you don't need the `$` there. Following does not produce the `Missing $ inserted`.

[image]

### Notes:

- Not sure what the `.` means in your equations, but did you perhaps intend to use a `\cdot`?
- Your `cases` example in the comments had an extra `&` at the end. I have added that example in the MWE.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1}=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
A.s.k_{t}^{\alpha}+(1-\delta).b_{t}^{P}-\delta.b_{t} \quad \text{if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} < 1$} \\ 
s.k_{t}^{\alpha}-b_{t} \quad \text{if $\frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} \geq 1$}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
k_{t+1}=
\begin{cases}
    A.s.k_{t}^{\alpha}+(1-\delta).b_{t}^{P}-\delta.b_{t} 
        & \quad \text{if } \frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} < 1 
        \\ 
    s.k_{t}^{\alpha}-b_{t} 
        & \quad \text{if } \frac{b_{t}+b_{t}^{P}}{(1-\epsilon).s.k_{t}^{\alpha}} \geq 1
\end{cases} 
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```